# How to remove repeated lines in an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Query

```
SELECT t1.table_id FROM TABLE_ONE t1, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'
    AND t1.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT t2.table_id FROM TABLE_ONE t2, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t2.table_name = 'TEST_TWO'
    AND t2.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT t3.table_id FROM TABLE_ONE t3, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t3.table_name = 'TEST_THREE'
    AND t3.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT tc1.table_id FROM TABLE_CHILD_ONE tc1, TABLE_ONE t1, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        tc1.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_ONE'
    AND tc1.table_id = t1.table_id
    AND t3.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

I would like to remove the repeated lines

```
AND cmn.column_one > 20
AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

and put it at the end. Can you kindly help me out? The problem of using joins as mentioned in answers is, I m not sure as how to put joins with child tables too. I had the option of using nested select. But was trying to use joins for better performance.

Comment: You don't have any join conditions between the `tX` and `cmn`, do you really want a cartesian product?

Comment: oh yeah, i must have considered joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite this query with join syntax like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.table_id
FROM   TABLE_ONE t
       JOIN COMMON_TABLE cmn
         ON t.table_id = cmn.common_id
WHERE  t.table_name IN( 'TEST_ONE', 'TEST_TWO', 'TEST_THREE' )
       AND cmn.column_one > 20
       AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

`DISTINCT` will remove duplicate records.

EDIT :

you can include your child table like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.table_id
FROM   TABLE_ONE t
       JOIN COMMON_TABLE cmn
         ON t.table_id = cmn.common_id
       JOIN TABLE_CHILD_ONE tc
         ON t.table_id = tc.table_id
WHERE  ( tc.table_name IN( 'TEST_CHILD_ONE', 'TEST_CHILD_TWO', 'TEST_CHILD_THREE' )
          OR t.table_name IN( 'TEST_ONE', 'TEST_TWO', 'TEST_THREE' ) )
       AND cmn.column_one > 20
       AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

Comment: Thank You. But the other problem what I will have with this query is , I will have condition checks for child tables. which will include t1 and t1_childtable.

Comment: means you have another table `t1_childtable` that you have included with `t1` and `cmn` in first query. if so, can you update this in your example?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove common limit condition like below

```
 SELECT table_id FROM 
    (SELECT t1.table_id, cmn.column_one, cmn.column_two  FROM TABLE_ONE t1, COMMON_TABLE cmn
      WHERE
            t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'
    UNION
      SELECT t2.table_id, cmn.column_one, cmn.column_two  FROM TABLE_ONE t2, COMMON_TABLE cmn
      WHERE
            t2.table_name = 'TEST_TWO'
    UNION
      SELECT t3.table_id, cmn.column_one, cmn.column_two  FROM TABLE_ONE t3, COMMON_TABLE cmn
      WHERE
            t3.table_name = 'TEST_THREE') AS MyTable
            WHERE
        column_one > 20
        column_two <= 30
```

Comment: The above code will work but on performance point of view it might take a long time on large set of records.

Comment: I had the same issue. That was the reason I removed the two Selects. All the table that i have, contain billions of rows.

Comment: @Sudharsanan: Oracle's optimizer can do predicate push-down. This is likely to have the same execution plan as the original SQL.

Comment: @Mat I dont know about predicate push-down, but eventually the above query took large span of time.

Comment: @Vikram: your cartesian products can't help. Make sure your stats are up to date too, and indexes are present if necessary.