# How to remove repeated lines in an Oracle SQL query for multiple parent and child tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Yesterday I posted a question regarding oracle sql query being repeated.

[How to remove repeated lines in an Oracle SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965909/how-to-remove-repeated-lines-in-an-oracle-sql-query)

How do I modify the SQL Query with JOIN if I have multiple parent and child tables?

```
SELECT t1.table_id FROM TABLE_ONE t1, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'
    AND t1.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT t2.table_id FROM TABLE_TWO t2, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t2.table_name = 'TEST_TWO'
    AND t2.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT t3.table_id FROM TABLE_THREE t3, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        t3.table_name = 'TEST_THREE'
    AND t3.table_id = cmn.common_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT tc1.table_id FROM TABLE_CHILD_ONE tc1, TABLE_ONE t1, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        tc1.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_ONE'
    AND tc1.table_id = t1.table_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
UNION
  SELECT tc2.table_id FROM TABLE_CHILD_TWO tc2, TABLE_TWO t2, COMMON_TABLE cmn
  WHERE
        tc2.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_TWO'
    AND tc2.table_id = t2.table_id
    AND cmn.column_one > 20
    AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

I would like to remove the repeated lines

```
AND cmn.column_one > 20
AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

Comment: P.S I have already tried cartisian product, nested select queries.. But mainly due to performance impact I could not afford to use it, since all my tables contain millions of rows in it.

Comment: Do you really need all of these `WHERE t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'` … `tc1.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_ONE'`? If these are indeed reflecting sub-partitioning of your data, is there possibly a chance to split the data over even more tables? Did you check your indexing?

Comment: Yeah its just sample data, but in my original query i have many rows plus conditions similar to the above one

Comment: You have three times `AND t3.table_id = cmn.common_id` up here. Do you in your real query too?

Comment: my bad. i edited the query now. I donot have something like that. copy paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `UNION` and get the values from all tables and then do one JOIN with COMMON_TABLE

```
SELECT table_id 
FROM 
(
   SELECT t1.table_id FROM TABLE_ONE t1 
   WHERE  t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'
   UNION 
   SELECT t2.table_id FROM TABLE_TWO t2
   WHERE  t2.table_name = 'TEST_TWO'
   UNION
   SELECT tc1.table_id FROM TABLE_CHILD_ONE tc1
   JOIN TABLE_ONE t1
   ON tc1.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_ONE'
   AND tc1.table_id = t1.table_id
) T
JOIN COMMON_TABLE cmn
ON T.table_id = cmn.common_id
AND cmn.column_one > 20
AND cmn.column_two <= 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
select table_id
from 
(
select table_id, cmn.column_one, cmn.column_two
etc
) derived_table
where column_one > 20
and column_two <= 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UNION ALL` unless you really need the data consolidation, which `UNION` does provide - and which comes at a performance penalty.

(Adjusted the join conditions - no longer three times `AND t3.table_id = cmn.common_id`).

Just drop the `ALL` where you need it due to your data's  intricacies:

```
SELECT table_id
FROM (
  (SELECT
    t1.table_id
  FROM TABLE_ONE t1
  WHERE t1.table_name = 'TEST_ONE'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tc1.table_id
  FROM TABLE_CHILD_ONE tc1
  JOIN TABLE_ONE t1
    ON tc1.table_id = t1.table_id
  WHERE tc1.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_ONE'
  )
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT t2.table_id
  FROM TABLE_TWO t2
  WHERE t2.table_name = 'TEST_TWO'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tc2.table_id
  FROM TABLE_CHILD_TWO tc2
  JOIN TABLE_TWO t2
    ON tc2.table_id = t2.table_id
  WHERE tc2.table_name = 'TEST_CHILD_TWO'
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.table_id
FROM TABLE_THREE t3
WHERE t3.table_name = 'TEST_THREE') T
JOIN COMMON_TABLE cmn
  ON T.table_id = cmn.common_id
WHERE cmn.column_one > 20
AND cmn.column_two <= 30;
```